# Implement mutable enumeration method on 2D grid

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I have a mostly working implementation of a 2D grid in rust:

```rust
use itertools::Itertools;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Grid<T> {
    width: usize,
    height: usize,
    items: Vec<T>,
}

impl<T> Grid<T> {
    pub fn new(width: usize, height: usize, initializer: impl Fn() -> T) -> Self {
        Self {
            width,
            height,
            items: (0..height * width).map(|_| initializer()).collect(),
        }
    }

    pub fn width(&self) -> usize {
        self.width
    }

    pub fn height(&self) -> usize {
        self.height
    }

    pub fn size(&self) -> usize {
        self.width * self.height
    }

    pub fn get(&self, x: usize, y: usize) -> Result<&T, &str> {
        if self.on_grid(x as isize, y as isize) {
            Ok(&self.items[self.coordinate_to_index(x, y)])
        } else {
            Err("coordinate not on grid")
        }
    }

    pub fn get_mut(&mut self, x: usize, y: usize) -> Result<&mut T, &str> {
        if self.on_grid(x as isize, y as isize) {
            let index = self.coordinate_to_index(x, y);
            Ok(&mut self.items[index])
        } else {
            Err("coordinate not on grid")
        }
    }

    pub fn iter(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = &T> {
        self.items.iter()
    }

    pub fn iter_mut(&mut self) -> impl Iterator<Item = &mut T> {
        self.items.iter_mut()
    }

    pub fn enumerate(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = (usize, usize, &T)> {
        self.items.iter().enumerate().map(|(index, item)| {
            let (x, y) = self.index_to_coordinate(index);
            (x, y, item)
        })
    }

    pub fn enumerate_mut(&mut self) -> impl Iterator<Item = (usize, usize, &mut T)> {
        self.items.iter_mut().enumerate().map(move |(index, item)| {
            let (x, y) = self.index_to_coordinate(index);
            (x, y, item)
        })
    }

    pub fn neighbors(&self, x: usize, y: usize) -> impl Iterator<Item = (usize, usize, &T)> {
        self.neighbor_indices(x, y)
            .map(|(x, y)| (x, y, &self.items[self.coordinate_to_index(x, y)]))
    }

    fn coordinate_to_index(&self, x: usize, y: usize) -> usize {
        y * self.width + x
    }

    fn index_to_coordinate(&self, index: usize) -> (usize, usize) {
        let x = index % self.width;
        let y = (index - x) / self.width;
        (x, y)
    }

    fn neighbor_indices(&self, x: usize, y: usize) -> impl Iterator<Item = (usize, usize)> + '_ {
        neighbor_offsets(2)
            .map(move |item| (x as isize + item[0], y as isize + item[1]))
            .filter(|&(x, y)| self.on_grid(x, y))
            .map(|(dx, dy)| (dx as usize, dy as usize))
    }

    fn on_grid(&self, x: isize, y: isize) -> bool {
        0 <= x && x < self.width as isize && 0 <= y && y < self.height as isize
    }
}

fn neighbor_offsets(dimension: usize) -> impl Iterator<Item = Vec<isize>> {
    (-1..1)
        .map(|index| index as isize)
        .combinations_with_replacement(dimension)
        // skip zero offset
        .filter(|items| !items.iter().all(|&item| item == 0))
}
```

`Cargo.toml`

```ini
[package]
name = "grid"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
itertools = "*"
```

However, with `enumerate_mut()` the compilation currently fails with

```
$ cargo build
   Compiling either v1.8.0
   Compiling itertools v0.10.5
   Compiling grid v0.1.0 (/home/neumann/Projekte/grid)
error[E0505]: cannot move out of `self` because it is borrowed
  --> src/lib.rs:64:47
   |
63 |       pub fn enumerate_mut(&mut self) -> impl Iterator<Item = (usize, usize, &mut T)> {
   |                            - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
64 |           self.items.iter_mut().enumerate().map(move |(index, item)| {
   |           ---------------------                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ move out of `self` occurs here
   |           |
   |  _________borrow of `self.items` occurs here
   | |
65 | |             let (x, y) = self.index_to_coordinate(index);
   | |                          ---- move occurs due to use in closure
66 | |             (x, y, item)
67 | |         })
   | |__________- returning this value requires that `self.items` is borrowed for `'1`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0505`.
error: could not compile `grid` due to previous error
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
```

I know that I *could* write the method `index_to_coordinate()` as a pure function, but I would like a solution, that uses the member function similarly to `enumerate()`.
Can this be done? If so, how?

Comment: By creating your own iterator, does this match our expectations? The problem is already the call of `self.items.iter_mut()` which doesn't allow any access of `self` anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like a solution, that uses the member function similarly to enumerate(). Can this be done? If so, how?

**It cannot be done**. You cannot borrow `self` while `self.items` is mutably borrowed. Full stop. Consider this formulation that *does* work without a member function:

```
pub fn enumerate_mut(&mut self) -> impl Iterator<Item = (usize, usize, &mut T)> {
    self.items.iter_mut().enumerate().map(|(index, item)| {
        let x = index % self.width;
        let y = (index - x) / self.width;
        (x, y, item)
    })
}
```

The only way this works is because of [disjoint borrows](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/borrow-splitting.html), i.e. the compiler knows that `.width` and `.height` are completely separate objects from `.items` (and actually this only works in 2021 edition since the disjoint borrows happen both inside and outside the closure). If you use a member of `self` though, the compiler has lost that knowledge and has to consider that `self` can access `items` within that member function, which wouldn't be allowed since the mutable borrow earlier must stay exclusive. Using the member function in the `enumerate()` method works since immutable borrows can be shared.

Function signatures are the contracts that borrow-checking, type-checking, and type-inference build off of. If the member function has access to `self`, it must be assumed that it will access *all* of `self`. There is no syntax for partial-borrows across a function interface.

---

*It cannot be done at all? Even if I used `unsafe`?*

Even with `unsafe`, you are not allowed to violate Rust's borrowing rules, so you can't have a `&Self` while its `.items` is mutably borrowed. You *can* access the `.width` and `.height` but it must be done via a *pointer*: `*const Self`. Here's what that'd look like (tested with Miri on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7ae79a3844faa88895e070d1a10a2b8b)):

```
pub fn enumerate_mut(&mut self) -> impl Iterator<Item = (usize, usize, &mut T)> {
    let this = self as *const Self;
    self.items.iter_mut().enumerate().map(move |(index, item)| {
        let (x, y) = unsafe { Self::index_to_coordinate(this, index) };
        (x, y, item)
    })
}

unsafe fn index_to_coordinate(this: *const Self, index: usize) -> (usize, usize) {
    let width = *std::ptr::addr_of!((*this).width);
    let height = *std::ptr::addr_of!((*this).height);
    let x = index % width;
    let y = (index - x) / width;
    (x, y)
}
```

However, I hope we can agree that this wouldn't be a *member* function anymore since it is lacking the `self.index_to_coordinate` syntax. Of course I'm not advocating you use this at all, it's just a demonstration that even going to the absurd it is not possible.

Just use a free function. :)